# Python PDF Merger with Windows "Send To" context menu

Tags: python, eof, pypdf

I'm trying to make use of the Windows "Send To" context menu to parse some PDF files to a PyPDF2 merger function.

as a sidenote:
The merger works fine when I apply it to a folder and run 
`os.listdir('folder')`

I've tried to pinpoint the problem and it came up  with a 'EOF' error. 
The pdf files have a valid EOF marker and I've tested the code with multiple PDF's.

Code:

```
import sys
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger


def pdfMerger(files, loc):
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for pdf in files:
        try:
            merger.append(open(pdf, 'rb'))
        except Exception as E:
            input(E)
    with open(loc + '/combined_pdf.pdf', 'wb') as pdf_out:
        merger.write(pdf_out)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        pdfMerger(sys.argv, os.path.split(sys.argv[1])[0])
```

Could somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, figured it out:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

'''
Description:
Merge PDF files in to 1 pdf file in source directory.
'''

import os
import sys
try:
    from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
except ImportError as missingModule:
    print('could not import PyPDF2', missingModule)


def checkType(arg):
    # check if given argument is a directory
    if os.path.isdir(arg[1]):
        # distil the source path
        arg = str(arg[1])
        # create a list with only pdf files
        pdf_files = [os.path.join(arg, f) for f in os.listdir(arg) if f.endswith('pdf')]
        src_loc = arg
        return pdf_files, src_loc
    # if arguments are pdf files, distil source folder and pdf files
    src_loc = os.path.split(sys.argv[1])[0]
    pdf_files = sys.argv[1:]
    return pdf_files, src_loc


def pdfMerger(args):
    files = args[0]
    loc = args[1]
    merger = PdfFileMerger(strict=False)
    for pdf in files:
        try:
            merger.append(open(pdf, 'rb'))
        except Exception as E:
            input(E)
    with open(loc + '/combined_pdf.pdf', 'wb') as pdf_out:
        merger.write(pdf_out)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 1:
        print('Usage: Python PFM.py [directory] / [file, file, etc.]')
    pdfMerger(checkType(sys.argv))
```

Answer (score 0):

after to read the last answer, i fix the code and now is usable in context-menu and sento menu here is the code:

```
'''
Description:
Merge PDF files in to 1 pdf file in source directory.
'''

import os
import sys
try:
    from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger
except ImportError as missingModule:
    print('could not import PyPDF2', missingModule)


def checkType(arg):
    # check if given argument is a directory
    if os.path.isdir(arg[1]):
        # distil the source path
        arg = str(arg[1])
        # create a list with only pdf files
        pdf_files = [os.path.join(arg, f) for f in os.listdir(arg) if f.endswith('pdf')]
        src_loc = arg
        return pdf_files, src_loc
    # if arguments are pdf files, distil source folder and pdf files
    src_loc = os.path.split(sys.argv[1])[0]
    pdf_files = sys.argv[1:]
    return pdf_files, src_loc


def pdfMerger(args):
    files = args[0]
    loc = args[1]
    merger = PdfMerger(strict=False)
    for pdf in files:
        try:
            merger.append(open(pdf, 'rb'))
        except Exception as E:
            input(E)
    with open(loc +'/combined.pdf', 'wb') as pdf_out:
        merger.write(pdf_out)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 1:
        print('Usage: Python PFM.py [directory] / [file, file, etc.]')
    pdfMerger(checkType(sys.argv))
```